# elastic search will not start

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am running mac osx. I installed elasticsearch with "pip install elasticsearch". I cannot start the elasticsearch server. None of the start commands I tried work. For example, "bin/elasticsearch -f" resulted in "No such file or directory". Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Basically using "pip install elasticsearch" only allows you to use elasticsearch directly in python (my theory). So I installed elasticsearch a different way and it worked!

Procedure:
a) brew install elasticsearch
b) elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

Answer (score 3):

What is the version of elasticsearch you are using and from where you have downloaded it?

On my Mac OS I have downloaded the zip file from elasticsearch download website. 
Unzipped it on my machine.
and Started the ES using "./bin/elasticsearch -f" command.

Check that you have permission on this files in bin directory.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh. Your suggestion led me to the actual solution shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## For mac if installed using homebrew

Navigates to /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.7.0(your version)/libexec/config/elasticsearch.yml

and from below mentioned block
Use a descriptive name for your cluster:

change cluster name as show below

## cluster.name: elasticsearch_your_system_name >>> cluster.name:elaticsearch